How can I access the ultra-wide camera in Flutter? I can’t get it via the camera plugin or Camera2 API. The camera manager shows no results
I am trying to access the ultra-wide camera on my device through a Flutter app using the camera plugin, but I'm unable to get a list of all available cameras. I need to show the ultra-wide camera zoom level in the Flutter UI and allow users to switch to it upon clicking.
I have tried accessing the camera using the native Camera2 API, but it returns the same results. I also checked the physical and logical camera arrays, but they are empty. How can I access the ultra-wide camera if the CameraManager does not detect it?
Any guidance on how to access and use the ultra-wide camera would be greatly appreciated
I tried accessing the ultra-wide camera using both the Flutter camera plugin and the Camera2 API. I expected to see the ultra-wide camera listed and be able to switch to it in the UI. However, neither method shows the ultra-wide camera, and the camera manager doesn't detect it.
